# Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 11, and there are 10 supplied

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I´m Learning Coding and the Error Message from the Debugging confuse me a bit,
when i try to create a SQLlite Database with 11 statements, i have two different Errors.

here my Code:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("wtime1.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()



date = ("31.10.2022")
p_unit = ("MMO")
equip = ("D014-K-00001")
report_prio = ("1")
order_prio = ("2")
job = ("Oel wechsel")
w_time = ("120")
fte = ("2")
reason = ("Kein Oel vorhanden")
cause = ("MAR 2")
solved = ("Erledigt")

mar2_list = ([date, p_unit, equip, report_prio, order_prio, job, w_time, fte, reason, cause, solved])


cursor.execute("create table if not exists mar21 (DATE integer, P_UNIT text, EQUIP text, REPORT_PRIO text, ORDER_PRIO text, JOB text, W_TIME integer, FTE integer, REASON text, CAUSE text, SOLVED text)")
cursor.executemany("insert into mar21 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", mar2_list)
```

the first Error:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 11, and there are 10 supplied.
  File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\Wartezeiten\db_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.executemany("insert into mar21 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", mar2_list)
```

Okay i found in my search i need one more comma at the end of the Values
when i set the comma like this

```
cursor.executemany("insert into mar21 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)", mar2_list)
```

i have a syntax error

```
near ")": syntax error
  File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\Wartezeiten\db_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.executemany("insert into mar21 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)", mar2_list)
```

i think i´m running a wrong way with the "insert values" line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have one record use `execute` instead of `executemany`

```
cursor.execute("insert into mar21 values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", mar2_list)
```